# Как заполнить таблицу в одном документе Word данными из таблицы Excel с помощью макроса VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, visual-basic, макросы

Всех приветствую!
Возникла задача автоматизации формирования таблицы в документе Word из данных, вводимых в таблицу Excel.

1. **Имеется таблица Excel**

Примерный формат приведён ниже, с неопределенным количеством вводимых данных, но со строго указанной формой. Необходимо при нажатии клавиши формировать таблицу в Word документе. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. **Имеется сам типовой Word документ**
   Таблица в документе должна быть заполнена данными из таблицы Excel и в зависимости от количества пунктов (№ п/п) расширяться полями (в качестве примера приведены пустые поля).
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Имеется пример кода, который нашел на просторах интернета:
   Думал переделать под свои задачи, но пока не знаю с чего именно начать.

```html
Sub main()
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object

HomeDir$ = ThisWorkbook.Path
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
i% = 2
Do
If Cells(i%, 1).Value = "" Then Exit Do
If Cells(i%, 1).Value <> "" Then

NPP$ = Cells(i%, 1).Text
ID$ = Cells(i%, 2).Text
Adress$ = Cells(i%, 3).Text
SN$ = Cells(i%, 4).Text

DataC$ = Date

FileCopy HomeDir$ + "\template.doc", HomeDir$ + "\" + NPP$ + "_" + ID$ + "_" + DataC$ + ".doc"
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(HomeDir$ + "\" + NPP$ + "_" + ID$ + "_" + DataC$ + ".doc")

wdDoc.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="&date", ReplaceWith:=DataC$

wdDoc.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="&id", ReplaceWith:=ID$
wdDoc.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="&adress", ReplaceWith:=Adress$
wdDoc.Range.Find.Execute FindText:="&sn", ReplaceWith:=SN$

wdDoc.Save
wdDoc.Close
End If

i% = i% + 1
Loop
wdApp.Quit
MsgBox "Готово!"

End Sub
```

**Подскажите, как это реализовать с применением макросов VBA?
Буду рад любой помощи, примерам кода, алгоритму как это делать.** Прочесал форумы, но не нашел необходимой информации, хоть и задача является типичной.

Comment: Преобразовать таблицу в `Excel` (если нужно, создать новую на основе исходной) к такому виду, как показана в `Word`. В месте вставки таблицы  (в `Word`) сделать закладку. Теперь макросом из `Excel` можна вставить в закладку преобразованную таблицу.

Comment: @vikttur, Необходимо именно с кнопки с исходной структурой Excel, потому что будет еще одна клавиша, которая формирует отчет по каждой строке. Если сделать такую же таблицу в Excel, то процесс заполнения будет примерно таким же по трудоемкости, как и заполнение таблицы в Word. Если я правильно понял ваш ответ.

Comment: Кто мешает перед копированием в `Word` запускать создание таблицы? Создается лист, на нем создается таблица, после копирования лист удаляется. Это если совсем скрыть действия от вражеских шпионов. Как по мне, лучше загодя создать лист с шаблоном таблицы, который будет заполняться (все тем же макросом) перед копированием таблицы.

Comment: @vikttur, Я буду благодарен, если вы опишите более подробно это в ответ, пока не совсем понял, из-за недостатков знаний.

Comment: Увы, это выходит за рамки простой помощи - нужно писать код, а это время. А что описывать? Закладка в шаблоне  документа и шаблон таблицы в Excel создаются заранее и используются каждый раз при необходимости. Макросом брать данные из готовой таблицы, переставить их и вставить в шаблон. Это одна задача. Вторая - связь с Word и вставка таблицы в закладку.

Comment: Переводите документы в Excel и жить станет гораздо легче.  Тем более, что это табличный документ.